# Service Broker-Certificate Not Found

Tags: service-broker

My organization has been successfully using service broker, dialog security, for a few years.

I have a new instance of service broker that I would like to configure, but I believe I am running into a situation where the order in which the new broker instance is being incorrectly placed into the databases (with existing broker instances in place) causing the new broker instance to fail.

My error is on the target server; Certificate Not Found. Security context could not be retrieved.

My situation is:
Source server A (dmz) sending to target server B, where there are already existing broker instances sending messages both ways but on different databases.

Test 1: I switched the role of the source and target server around, making server B my source and server A (dmz) my target while using the same databases.  This was successful.

Test 2: I dropped the test 1 instance and created 2 new databases on each server. I have again, reconfigured the source and target roles, now sending from server A (dmz) to server B and this was successful. There is only the one service broker instance configured in the new databases, so the order of placement is not an issue.

I have come into this situation in the past when we first set up our dev/test environments; However, the situation was slightly different as many other broker instances were also failing. Not all of them, but some. Once I realized what was happening, dropping all instances and recreating them in a specific order, source instances before target instances, the situation was resolved.

I would think that service broker would add a new instance in the correct place of order, automatically.

Am I correct in thinking that the broker instances must be configured within a specific order? If so, how can I add new broker instances without interrupting what is already there?

Please share your thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: Multiple instances of a service (multiple DBs) should all share the same private keys. You cannot add a new instance *with a different key*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In hopes to clear some confusion, I believe what you are saying is; if I have service A on DB1 and service A on DB2 then add another broker instance (say service B) using the same DB1 and DB2, then service B should use the same private key as service A. But now I question; when we have a third broker instance (service C) on DB2 and service C on DB3, shouldn't the broker instance for service C have a different key than service A and B?

Comment: Is the service C and DB2 owned by the same user (dbo?) as the service  B on DB2? IF that is the case (and it usually is) then it cannot have another certificate, since the same identity owns both services.

Comment: We do use the same user for each service and certificate, though this is not the same user that owns the database. Test 1: Create new user and login, made user owner of the new certificate for new service. Target Error: No certificate found, Msg could not be delivered because the security context could not be retrieved. Test 2: Created new service without certificate, with intention of using pre-existing certificate. Same error as above, on target. Note: we are setting up new service from DB1 to DB2, there is a pre-existing service (diff. process) from DB2 to DB1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a profiler trace and monitor for [`Security Audit/Audit Broker Conversation`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191001(v=sql.110).aspx). Repro the issue, an event of this class should be produced. Look at the event details. It should shed light. I think two of the event columns (can't remeber which, and MSDN seems to omit the info) contain the problem certificate issuer name/serial number, which should further help narrow down *which* certificate is being used.

[Edit]
Run this query query on all three databases to find out which certificates are used by which service and remote service binding:

```
select s.name, c.* 
from sys.services s
join sys.certificates c
on s.principal_id = c.principal_id
where c.is_active_for_begin_dialog = 1
and pvt_key_encryption_type != 'NA'
order by c.expiry_date desc


select b.remote_service_name, b.remote_service_binding_id, c.* 
from sys.remote_service_bindings b
join sys.certificates c on b.remote_principal_id = c.principal_id
where c.is_active_for_begin_dialog = 1
order by c.expiry_date desc
```

[Edit after your data]

1) In PRd2DB services tab: all services in the DB are owned by `dbo`, and `dbo` owns 4 certificates that are valid for SSB (certificate ids 280, 288, 327 and 357). The xls did not correctly capture the `expiry_date` (is all 00:00.0) so I cannot know for sure which one is used, but if the results come from the query I posted above then the first one will be used, certificate id 280 with the serial number `54 89 2c 1a...`. So this is the certificate used to identify *any* service from this db.

2) In Prd2 in the RSB tab, the query shows a mixture of certificates with private key and ones without a private key. This should *never* happen. An user associated with an RSB represents the identity of a remote service and should own only certificates with **no** private key. Also, there is only one RSB user (the one with principal_id 58) for all remote services. There should be a different identity user for *each* remote service. Right now any dialog started in PrdDB2, to any service, will use the certificate with serial number `34 99 ...`.

3) DMZDB1 services: same as prd2, all services owned by `dbo`, dbo has 3certificates (ids 335, 341, 371) and the one used will be the one with serial number `74 0a ...`

4) DMZDB RSBs: there are two RSB users, one principal id 9 and one 30. The principal id 9 has a mixture of certificates, including some with private key, while principal id 30 has only one certificate but that certificate has a private key.

Overall, the configuration is deeply flawed and and no wonder it doesn't work. You do not understand the role and the proper configuration of a remote service binding.

Please follow the following rules. Consider a remote service 'Foo':

- create a **different** user (principal) for each remote service, call it `remote_user_Foo`
- create a RSB for each remote service, using the principal for this service (ie. `remote_user_Foo`)
- The `remote_user_Foo` should own exactly one certificate, and it should not have a private key
- Grant necessary permissions (`SEND`) to `remote_user_Foo`

Next time you run the query for showing the RSB it should show a number of rows equal to the number of remote service bindings, the `principal_id` values should be all distinct and the `pvt_key_encryption_type` should all be `NA`.

Comment: It is showing me that my new service (trace column: TargetUserName) is indeed using the wrong certificate (trace column:DBUserName). A certificate that exists in DB1, but not in DB2. What are some reasons it might pick up the wrong certificate? The expiry date is the same across each cert.

Comment: Since you're talking about different services, there should be different identities. Which means different users, owning different certificates. Did you set up the Remote Service Binding for the new service reusing the previous service user?

Comment: Yes, same user. But in previous test cases, mentioned above, I have tested while creating a new user for my new service. This includes the Remote Service Binding as well as grant user send on service. I tested with and without a cert. Same situation occurs. It still looks at that one other certificate, even with new user. I have new error msg for test case without cert, as I just now tested again. Dialog security is unavailable for this conversation because there is no security certificate bound to the database principal (Id: 5). I create new cert with same new user, still looks at other cert.

Comment: Today I dropped my new sb instance and tried again. I created all the broker objects with a new user. I set it up with the dmz being the source and once again with it being the target. When it is the target, everything works. But I need it to be the source. I tried sending a msg from dmz when it was setup as target and still chose wrong cert. I set it up again with dmz being the source and added the route to msdb (we always use AutoLocal, vs. a specific route in msdb) with broker instance specified. Still uses wrong cert. Please let me know if you have any additional suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @Kourtney see my edit

Comment: Thank you Remus. I ran the scripts and it is showing me that each certificate is used by each service and each remote service binding. This would make since with each certificate, service and RSB that have the same user assigned. But my new certificate, service, and RSB have a different user than the rest. Still it is showing that my new certificate is used by each service and RSB. The cert that it is using has the oldest start date. Not sure if that is relevant information.

Comment: @Kourtney can you post here the output from the queries?

Comment: I have created a shared link to the documents containing the results. Please let me know if you have any troubles with this. Thanks.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zPnsAhBMWD24RTKeT1hORXAHJ98BVNvF

Comment: NOTE: In the documents you will see source and target "DMZ-DMZDB1--PROD-PRDDB2", and this is the newly added cert/service with password different from the rest. The issue is with the new service using the "DB2Web" cert, instead of the new cert. I originally intended on using this cert "PROD-PRDDB2--DMZ-DMZDB1".

Comment: Thank you for all your help, as I was able to successfully configure the new service broker instance across the  environments using your suggestions. However; I was hoping you might be able to explain to me why all the other service broker instances (with same user) are working as expected? With your suggestion and my most recent experience, I would think no other sb instances would be working, but they are all using correct certificates.  As of current, all sb instances are assigned to all certs, even new one. But my new user is only assigned to one (proper) cert. Same with RSB.

Comment: With allowed time, I will have to go into each environment and reconfigure everything that came before me, but I am seeking better understanding of what I am facing. Thank you